# .pcap file cannot be read using vlpgrabber

Tags: double, free, corruption

I am having another (below) issue while reading .pcap file using vlpgrabber:

**double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)**

void VLP16::Start(std::string pcapName)
{

```
mVlpGrabber = boost::shared_ptr<pcl::VLPGrabber>(new pcl::VLPGrabber(pcapName));
    Start();
```

}

in the header file, mVlpGrabber is declared as  ----->

class VLP16
{
private:
boost::shared_ptrpcl::VLPGrabber mVlpGrabber;

.
.
.
}

Once the code is built, in the command window, I write (I kept the .pcap file inside build folder for convenience):

./vlp16 -pcap "2023-05-18-10-45-31_Velodyne-VLP-16-Data.pcap"

Any suggestions please?

NB: I am using PCL 1.13 , C++17 and Ubuntu 20

I tried to read .pcap file and expecting to read point cloud data out of it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.